# Desaturate image when scrolling behind an element

Tags: javascript, css, image, html, canvas

I have an 'Is this possible on a canvas' question. Say I have a fixed div element on the page with it's background color set and make it opaque. Now when another element (an image) scrolls behind, it can be seen through the fixed div on top.

Now, I'd like to do this, except the full color image behind will desaturate (i.e. become opaque, greyscale) where the top div is covering it. I can't find any way this can be done with CSS3, nor does it seem possible to manipulate pixels with straight up javascript.

So I guess I'm wondering if the canvas element can detect standard overlapping DOM elements and redraw them on the surface. Or are there any other ways to tackle this? I don't want to make the whole page a canvas (for non html5 browsers), and flash is not an option.

Your thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: So if I had a translucent white div, an image would desaturate behind it. What you want to do is make it so that the image _doesn't_ desaturate?

Comment: Is this a "one off image" that you can manually desaturate using Photoshop beforehand? Or does it need to be able to work with any image?

Comment: @JamWaffles, My apologies, I should have been clearer on this. I do want it to desaturate. By desaturate I mean 'turn to greyscale'. An opaque top element bleeds color as well.

Comment: @thirtydot, This should happen 'live' on a webpage with any full color image that scrolls behind. Also, I only want to desaturate the part of the image that is covered by the top element (not the whole image at once) I hope that answers your question?

Comment: @Adrian: I'm not sure, but this should be possible with a canvas, however it would be pretty complex and not very cross browser, so maybe just leaving the colour to bleed through is the simplest option.

Comment: @Adrian: It helps, but I specifically want to know: is it an option to make two versions of the image, one "full colour", and one "desaturated"? I'm aware that you only want to desaturate a part, and that the part will change as the image moves.

Comment: @JamWaffles, yes I may have to put this in the 'too hard basket'. I can imagine monitoring the position of a bunch of images on the page, then drawing parts of them onto the canvas when coordinates overlap. Which also sounds like a lot of effort.

Comment: I can see a demo would be handy here. It would be similar to the vanishingelephant.com/press/ header

Comment: @thirtydot, great idea - I'll have a closer look at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was interesting to me, so I implemented a solution.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/3eHmD/show/ ([edit](http://jsfiddle.net/3eHmD/))

- It will work in "all browsers".
- It uses jQuery.
- It uses pre-rendered images:

  [image]
  [image]
- It doesn't have to use pre-rendered images. To avoid pre-rendering, I'd use [Pixastic's](http://www.pixastic.com/) desaturate (http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/desaturate/).

**JavaScript:** *(could be improved)*

```
var $fixed = $('.fixed');
var $source = $('.content');

var $fixedCopy = $('<div class="fixedDimensions"></div>').appendTo('body').css('zIndex', 99);
var $contentCopy = $source.clone().appendTo($fixedCopy);


$contentCopy.find(':not(.magic)').css('visibility', 'hidden');
$contentCopy.find('.magic').each(function() {
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', $(this).width() + 'px 0');
});

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    $contentCopy.css('margin-top',-$(window).scrollTop());
}).scroll();
```

**CSS:**

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
body {
    background: #eee
}

.content {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto
}
#fixed {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKWv7.png);
    color: red;
    font: 36px sans-serif;
    text-align: center
}
.fixedDimensions {
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="fixed" class="fixedDimensions">Hello</div>

<div id="container">
    <div class="content">
        <p><div class="magic" style="width:200px;height:300px;background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3LRY.jpg)"></div></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
        <p><div class="magic" style="width:225px;height:300px;background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D8gh.jpg)"></div></p>
        <p>Aenean et diam dui..</p>
        ..
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Genius. I was just about to throw this one in the too hard basket. Thank you so much thirtydot!

Answer (score 1):

Others have provided solutions that may or may not be better for what you want to do. In the interest of completeness, to answer your question of "is this possible on a Canvas?"

Yes, de-saturation can be done with a canvas. Here is how:

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,can.width, can.height);
var pixels = imageData.data;
var numPixels = pixels.length;

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

for (var i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
    var average = (pixels[i*4] + pixels[i*4+1] + pixels[i*4+2]) /3;
    // set red green and blue pixels to the average value
    pixels[i*4] = average;
    pixels[i*4+1] = average;
    pixels[i*4+2] = average;
}
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

You average the color of the three existing colors to get the average brightness of color. Then you set all three colors to the same value to get gray at the average brightness. Make sense?

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/DZmyB/4/

Comment: Thanks for the tip Simon. I guess my initial question was a bit misleading, perhaps I should have asked if portions of an image could be manipulated using canvas in some way. Turns out canvas is not needed if two versions of the image are loaded (at least in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use jQuery, you might want to look at the [jQuery Desaturate plugin](http://dev.artutkin.ru/desaturate/). I realize it doesn't do everything you want (it's simply saturating or desaturating an image), but it could get you some of the way there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip nrabinowitz, I was thinking I could poll the image position, overlay two images and use a css clip animation on a overlaying, desaturated image to reveal it. This plugin at least allows me to create the image on the fly instead of storing two server side. Still sounds like a lot of effort for the result, but this could work!